# Monitoring program on Virtual Machine

Tags: c, linux, debian, virtual-machine, monitoring

Here is some code on a VM (debian linux). It's actually work on my OS debian wheezy but not on the VM, I don't know why but I have some ideas about this. I think the VM can't access actual memory on VM because it's not shared.

Here is the code:

```
void check_single_process(function_handler *handle, pid_t pid)
{
    glibtop_proc_mem       procmem;
    glibtop_mem            mem;

    glibtop_get_proc_mem(&procmem, pid);
    glibtop_get_mem(&mem);

    handle->C.mem_used = (float)(100.0 * procmem.resident) / (float)mem.total;
}
```

Actually, on the VM, mem.total = 0. So I got a segmentation fault.
If anyone can explain me how it's possible and why, thank.